# Get link ID jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var loc = window.location.href
var fileNameIndex = loc.lastIndexOf("?") + 1;
var dotIndex = loc.lastIndexOf('#');
var output = loc.substr(fileNameIndex, dotIndex < fileNameIndex ? loc.length : dotIndex);
```

And here is my link :

```
Fideloo/live/index.html?5980d199c632d10093#index
```

I'd like to get only this : `5980d199c632d10093` instead of this `5980d199c632d10093#index`

Could someone give me a hand, I'd be very greatful.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, change `substr` to `substring`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var str = "Fideloo/live/index.html?5980d199c632d10093#index";
var res = str.split("?");
var r = res[1].split("#");
console.log(r[0]);
alert(r[0]);
```